# No toggle for dropdown item

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am a beginner with `html` and `bootstrap`, and I try to set a nice `nav-bar` with a `dropdown` item. I am currently reviewing the `nav-bar` from http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/, but the `dropdown` `toggle` does not happen in my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
        <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"></meta>
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"></meta>
        <meta content="" name="description"></meta>
        <meta content="" name="author"></meta>

        <title>Baroum</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/navbar-fixed-top.css"></link>
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#navbar" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Baroum</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                                Dropdown 
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Action</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Another action</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Something else here</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-header">
                                    Nav header
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Separated link</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code every thing works fine

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
        <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"></meta>
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"></meta>
        <meta content="" name="description"></meta>
        <meta content="" name="author"></meta>

        <title>Baroum</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

       
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Bootstrap, from Twitter</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <style>
      body {
        padding-top: 60px;
      }
      @media (max-width: 979px) {

        /* Remove any padding from the body */
        body {
          padding-top: 0;
        }
      }
    </style>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- Le fav and touch icons -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="images/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="images/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png" />
    <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="2.1.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap" data-semver="3.2.0" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#navbar" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Baroum</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                                Dropdown 
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Action</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Another action</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Something else here</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-header">
                                    Nav header
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Separated link</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
</html>
```

You can check this code on plunker its working fine.